# ProjectItemsEvents.ItemAdded: how can I discover the item type?

Tags: c#, .net, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'm beginning to develop a VSPackage and would like to know when a new reference is added to a project but subscribing the ItemAdded of ProjectItemsEvents gives me a ProjectItem object and I don't know how to check if it is a reference. Can somebody help me to solve that problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I found that the class VSLangProj.ReferencesEvents fire the     ReferenceAdded event I need. So, I've done:

```
private static ReferencesEvents _refEvents;
private static Events2 _dteEvents;
public void SubscribeEvents()
{
 EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
 _dteEvents = dte.Events as Events2;
 _refEvents = (ReferencesEvents)_dteEvents.GetObject("CSharpReferencesEvents");
 _refEvents.ReferenceAdded += new _dispReferencesEvents_ReferenceAddedEventHandler(ReferenceAdded);
}

private void ReferenceAdded(Reference pReference)
{
  // do some stuff.
}
```